# Linear Dependence of Vectors and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W=\left \{ w_{1},...,w_{m} \right \}$ and $V=\left \{ v_{1},...,v_{n} \right \}$ for $m>n$ where W and V are both independent sets of vectors. ($W$ being an independent set of vectors means $w_1,\cdots,w_m$ are independent. Similarly for $V$)

Why the following cannot be true?

> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> w_{1}\\ 
> w_{2}\\
> \vdots \\
> w_{m} \end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}
> a_{11} & &a_{1n} \\ 
> \vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\ 
>  a_{m1}&  & a_{mn}\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> v_{1}\\ 
> v_{2}\\
> \vdots \\
> v_{n} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: This question is very confusingly stated. First off, you are asking why some $X\neq Y$ **cannot** be true, which is equivalent to asking why $X=Y$ **must** be true, but I don't think that is what you mean (and if it were it would be a weird way to ask). Second, you are mixing matrix notation (at least the $a_{i,j}$ seem to form a matrix) with stacks of things that are *vectors*; the ordinary definition of matrix*vector multiplication requires a stack of _scalars_, i.e., a column vector. One could go guessing what you actually mean, but I would insist that you rephrase the question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows of $Av $ belong to the span of $v_1,\ldots,v_n $, which has dimension $n $. An $n $-dimensional space cannot contain  $m>n $ linearly independent vectors.

---

So, here is an argument that shows that if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ linearly independent and they span the same space, then $n=m$. We can write 
$$
w_k=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{kj}v_j
$$
for certain coefficients $\{\alpha_{kj}\}$. Similarly, we can write 
$$
v_j=\sum_{\ell=1}^m\beta_{j\ell}w_\ell
$$
for certain coefficients $\{\beta_{j\ell}\}$. Combining the two equalities, we get 
$$
w_k=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^m\alpha_{kj}\beta_{j\ell}\,w_\ell=\sum_{\ell=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{kj}\beta_{j\ell}\right)\,w_\ell.
$$
By the linear independence of $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ we obtain
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{kj}\beta_{j\ell}=\delta_{k\ell}.
$$
In particular, $$\tag{1}\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{kj}\beta_{jk}=\sum_{k=1}^m\delta_{kk}=m.$$
Now we can repeat all the above with the roles of $v_j$ and $w_k$ exchanged, and we obtain 
$$
v_j=\sum_{\ell=1}^m\sum_{h=1}^n\beta_{j\ell}\alpha_{\ell h}\,v_h
=\sum_{h=1}^n\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^m\beta_{j\ell}\alpha_{\ell h}\right)\,v_h,
$$
and so 
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^m\beta_{j\ell}\alpha_{\ell h}=\delta_{jh}.
$$
Thus,
$$\tag{2}
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^m\beta_{j\ell }\alpha_{\ell j}=\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{jj}=n.
$$
But the sums in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same, and so $m=n$.

Comment: I agree with you that this is true, and I hate to be picky. I feel as though referring to dimension in this sense is questionable; it makes me wonder why dimension of a spanning set is defined the way it is when you have to use it to prove algebraic equations like this. I feel the same way about using rank in this context. Essentially dimension proves rank. I am wanting an algebraic understanding of why this does not work. I appreciate the answer, but I am just wanting something more.

Comment: I don't follow: "cardinality of a linearly independent set" is precisely "dimension", and that's exactly the language used to formulate your problem. How do you expect to deal with this problem without using the hypothesis?

Comment: How do you know that dim(span(V)) is defined without knowing that equation might be false? Your dim(span(V)) could be different values then or in other words different sets of bases.

Comment: Of course, the argument depends on the fact that  if two sets of linearly independent vectors span the same set, then they have the same cardinality (that, is fact #1 of vector spaces). You won't avoid this fact in your argument, since without it your equality could be true.

Comment: So then why do two sets of linearly independent vectors that span the same set have the same cardinality?-If you are going to use that fact to prove the above equation.

Comment: In this case, the span(V)=span(W) correct?

Comment: Yes. I have included an argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62040/discussion-between-w-g-and-martin-argerami).

Comment: No thanks, I don't do chat. It is hard to read, separate from the question, you cannot notify people, nor get notified when a reply is made.

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to say thank you, and I appreciate your help. This helped me immensely!

Comment: Note that "I don't do chat". I don't mind the comment section.

Comment: I have been looking at great detail, and I am curious as to why span(V)=span(W)? I really did appreciate the answer as to why two linearly independent sets that span the same space have the same dimension, but I do not think span(V)=span(W) (but could be wrong). Rather, $span(W)\subseteq span(V)$.

Comment: It's irrelevant. If you have a proper inclusion $\text{span} W\subset\text{span}V$, you expand $W$ until you have equality.

Comment: But then you can't represent the $v_j=\sum_{\ell=1}^m\beta_{j\ell}w_\ell$ correct?

Comment: It would be $m+g$ for an appropriate $g$. Nothing else in the argument changes.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose otherwise one has the equality. Then one can write that 
$$
B=AC
$$
where $rank(B)=m$ and $rank(C)=n$. Now, by a [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) of matrix ranks:
$$
m=rank(B)\leq\min\{rank(A),rank(C)\}=\min\{rank(A),n\}
$$
which is impossible because by the assumption $m>n$.

---

[Added later.] I like Martin's answer better than mine: if the equality is true, then it follows that $span(W)\subset span(V)$, which is impossible since $m>n$.

Comment: How could you do a rank on a bunch of vectors?

Comment: Think in terms of *row* vectors. If all the row vectors of a matrix is linearly independent, then the rank of the matrix is equal to the number of its rows.

Comment: Why would you say that if all of the row vectors is linearly independent? What do you mean by a row vector being independent?

Comment: "If all the row vectors of a matrix is linearly independent" should really be "If all the row vectors of a matrix **are** linearly independent" in my previous comment. $w_1,\cdots,w_m$  are all *vectors*, right? Now consider them as *row vectors*. Write the matrix $B$ with $w_1$ as its first row, $w_2$ as the second row, etc.. Because $w_1,w_2,\cdots, w_m$ are linearly independent, namely, all the rows of $B$ are linearly independent, the rank of $B$ is $m$.

Comment: $w_1,\cdots,w_m$ being linearly independent means $b_1w_1+\cdots+b_mw_m=0$ implies $b_1=\cdots=b_m=0$.

Comment: Saying the set $W$ is a independent set is the same as saying $w_1,\cdots,w_m$ are linearly independent.